# Get usage time for individual apps programmatically iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, usage-statistics

Is it possible to get the usage time for each app on my iPhone programatically?
I want to create an app which tells me how much time I spend on each app on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **NO**

Longer answer: Just using a jailbreak.

Comment: How if i want to get on Jailbreak iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

No. Each app is isolated in its own sandbox. You can only receive usage information for **your** apps and not those by other developers. And that's only if you add that functionality yourself.

Answer (score 1):

From this code you can get starting time of the process

```
- (NSArray *)runningProcesses
{

int mib[4] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0};
size_t miblen = 4;

size_t size;
int st = sysctl(mib, miblen, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);

struct kinfo_proc * process = NULL;
struct kinfo_proc * newprocess = NULL;

do {

    size += size / 10;
    newprocess = realloc(process, size);

    if (!newprocess){

        if (process){
            free(process);
        }

        return nil;
    }

    process = newprocess;
    st = sysctl(mib, miblen, process, &size, NULL, 0);

} while (st == -1 && errno == ENOMEM);

if (st == 0){

    if (size % sizeof(struct kinfo_proc) == 0)
    {
        int nprocess = size / sizeof(struct kinfo_proc);

        if (nprocess)
        {

            array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for (int i = nprocess - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {

                processID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", process[i].kp_proc.p_pid];
                processName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", process[i].kp_proc.p_comm];
                NSString * processStartTime = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%ld", process[i].kp_proc.p_starttime.tv_sec];
                NSString * priority = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%hhu", process[i].kp_proc.p_priority];
                NSString * status = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", process[i].kp_proc.p_stat];

                NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:processID, processName,processStartTime,priority,status, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ProcessID", @"ProcessName",@"Time", @"Priority",@"Status", nil]];
                [array addObject:dict];
                 NSLog(@"PID %d",process[i].kp_proc.p_pid);
            }

            free(process);
            NSLog(@"Array %@",array);
        }
    }
}
return nil;
```

}

> Blockquote